# Printing text once sprite meets position

Tags: python, position, pygame, sprite

Currently I am working on a small 'space invaders' style game using pygame and I wanted to create various outcomes depending on the score / health level. I wish to make it so if the enemy ships have passed the player and the player has not yet met the score limit of 70 to pass the level, I want to display a message stating the target score has not been met.

I have this code so far which I think should allow this to happen:

```
        if block.rect.y == random.randrange(600) and health >=25 and score < 70:
            font = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf", 30)
            label = font.render("Score target not met", 1, (0,255,0))
            labelRect = label.get_rect()
            labelRect.center = (400, 250)
            break
```

Here it is shown in more detail:

```
for bullet in bullet_list:

    block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(bullet, block_list, True)

    for block in block_hit_list:
        explosion.play()
        bullet_list.remove(bullet)
        all_sprites_list.remove(bullet)
        score += 10

        if health >= 25 and score == 70:
            win.play()
            font = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf", 30)
            label = font.render("LEVEL COMPLETE!", 1, (0,255,0))
            labelRect = label.get_rect()
            labelRect.center = (400, 250)
            bullet_list.remove(bullet)
            all_sprites_list.remove(bullet)
            break

        if block.rect.y == random.randrange(600) and health >=25 and score < 70 and score > 0:
            font = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf", 30)
            label = font.render("Score target not met", 1, (0,255,0))
            labelRect = label.get_rect()
            labelRect.center = (400, 250)
            break

    if score >= 70:
        collision.stop()
        laser.stop()
        explosion.stop()
        bullet_list.remove(bullet)
        all_sprites_list.remove(bullet)
        block_list.remove(block)
        all_sprites_list.remove(block)
        player_list.remove(player)
        all_sprites_list.remove(player)

    if health == 0:
        laser.stop()
        bullet_list.remove(bullet)
        all_sprites_list.remove(bullet)

    if bullet.rect.y < -10:
        bullet_list.remove(bullet)
        all_sprites_list.remove(bullet)
```

However once I execute this code no text is actually pasted onto the window once the enemy ships have passed.

Heres my full code incase anyone knows why this is happening:

http://pastebin.com/C0V5MnSH

Comment: What's the intended purpose of comparing to `random.randrange(600)`?

Comment: @joconnor I was trying to say if the position of the ship = 600 then do what follows. As the screen is 800x600 I expected the game to realise the enemy ships were off / just about to be off the screen and so the "Score target not met" message was printed as no more enemy ships could be hit by the player ship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems that I can see. First, you shouldn't check for the enemies going off of the screen inside of

```
for bullet in bullet_list:
    for block in block_hit_list:
```

you should create a new line on the main loop.

Second, every time you call

```
random.randrange(600)
```

you get a new random number inbetween 0 and 600. So the following code has a sixth of a percent chance of being ran if block is still on the screen. If block goes of the screen, it has a 0 percent chance. Instead, write

```
if block.rect.y >= 600:
```

So the whole thing should look like:

```
for bullet in bullet_list:

    block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(bullet, block_list, True)

    for block in block_hit_list:
        explosion.play()
        bullet_list.remove(bullet)
        all_sprites_list.remove(bullet)
        score += 10

        if health >= 25 and score == 70:
            win.play()
            font = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf", 30)
            label = font.render("LEVEL COMPLETE!", 1, (0,255,0))
            labelRect = label.get_rect()
            labelRect.center = (400, 250)
            bullet_list.remove(bullet)
            all_sprites_list.remove(bullet)
            break

    if score >= 70:
        collision.stop()
        laser.stop()
        explosion.stop()
        bullet_list.remove(bullet)
        all_sprites_list.remove(bullet)
        block_list.remove(block)
        all_sprites_list.remove(block)
        player_list.remove(player)
        all_sprites_list.remove(player)

    if health == 0:
        laser.stop()
        bullet_list.remove(bullet)
        all_sprites_list.remove(bullet)

    if bullet.rect.y < -10:
        bullet_list.remove(bullet)
        all_sprites_list.remove(bullet)


if block.rect.y >= 600 and health >=25 and score < 70 and score > 0:
    font = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf", 30)
    label = font.render("Score target not met", 1, (0,255,0))
    labelRect = label.get_rect()
    labelRect.center = (400, 250)
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your reply! I implemented your suggestions however still no text is printed to the screen :( Heres my full updated code again incase ive made a silly / obvious mistake: http://pastebin.com/xAC0acmB

Comment: Update: The text does in fact get printed however this only happens if I avoid collisions with enemy ships and if I dont fire a bullet. Do you have any further idea as to why this might be? Thanks again for your reply

Comment: Update 2: I have gotten this to function correctly by ensuring that the 'if block.rect.y' line is situated within another for loop for block in block_list. Thanks for your feedback regardless, your help was crucial :D

Comment: Okay, glad to hear I could help!